# Cómo recuperar un valor de una función con @property

Tags: python, poo

Tengo esto

```
@property
def pitch(self):
    """ Calculates the Pitch of the Quaternion. """

    x, y, z, w = self.x, self.y, self.z, self.w
    return math.atan2(2*x*w - 2*y*z, 1 - 2*x*x - 2*z*z)
```

Pero cuando acedo al resultado, por ejemplo:

```
re=clase.pitch
print re
```

Me sale es un mensaje, yo necesito el número, ¿cómo puedo obtenerlo,?

**la función no se puedo modificar,  quitandole la propiedad hace parte de una libreria

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás confundiendo un poco las cosas. El método `pitch()` es una propiedad para las instancias de las clases, no para la clase misma. Por lo tanto lo que necesitas es:

```
re = clase(w, x, y, z) # Creas una instancia de la clase
print re.pitch
```

Ejemplo:

```
>>> re = clase(1,2,3,4)
>>> print re.pitch
-2.6677413171
```

Si intentas imprimir la propiedad usando la clase vas a obtener algo como esto que es seguramente el mensaje del que hablas en tu pregunta:

```
>>> print clase.pitch
<property object at 0x7ff4243e5680>
```